# Finding extent of MXD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, extents, mxd

I have a set of MXDs for layout view maps, and I would like to easily find out the four coordinates that define the extents (using the same units as the map projection).  What is the best way to do this?

Additional detail.  I have a CSV file with a table listing the extents for portions of 300 counties that a simple python program uses to automatically create county-specific MXDs and JPEGs.  Occasionally, I decide to alter the frame displayed for a given county, which is easily done in ArcMap to generate a single map.  But I would like to revise my table of extents so I can use the revised frame in the automatic process.

Comment: What do you mean by "four extents"? Add an image to your question to explain it better.

Comment: @Hornbydd:  I mean the four coordinates that define the frame of a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `extent` property of the MXD's `dataFrame` object that includes your map.

See the [DataFrame](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm) documentation

Eg, use the following Python code (assuming exactly 1 data frame in the MXD, and that the MXD is the currently open document):

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
extent = df.extent
print("({}, {})  ({}, {})".format(extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax))
```

You can run this code either manually in the ArcMap Python Window, or add it to a function within the 'Code Block' of a 'Calculate Value' item in a Model Builder model (then return the call to the function, and set the output type to 'Extent').

Comment: Thanks.  That worked for me, other than changing the second line in your code to      df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

Comment: Oops... typo fixed.  Thanks.